# Sending A postMessage in puppeteer (Nodejs Library)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-domain, puppeteer, postmessage

I know how to receive postMessages ,but I am looking to send a postMessage request to a site

Just a Format

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const yargs = require('yargs');

let command = yargs.argv._[0];

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();


function sendMessageToContentScriptByPostMessage(data)
{
    window.postMessage({cmd: 'message', data: data}, '*');
}

    await page.goto(command, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    await browser.close();


})();
```

So the user can do this, node postmessage.js https://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page.evaluate` to run things *inside the browser*. Then you can send a postMessage:

```
await page.evaluate((data) => {
  window.postMessage({cmd: 'message', data: data}, '*');
}, data);
```

Two things to keep in mind:

- the `evaluate` runs inside the browser, while all the other scripts are inside NodeJS (you can think of remote vs local code, local = NodeJS, remote = Chrome)
- because of this, variables inside the `evaluate` are different than outside. You need to explicitly pass the `data` to `evaluate` to move it into the browser context.

Comment: Okay So I made a script "https://pastebin.com/xYStdfbh" . It is giving reference Error and I know it is because data is not defined. Could you please see ?

Comment: And I was also Thinking about the scenario is it possible through "CreateCDPSession" in puppeteer ?

Comment: Here's a working example: https://pastebin.com/ZvDmCN8A . I'm using a headless browser here, but it prints the message to the console.